# What is the behavior of cancel query on pgadmin3

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I was irresponsibly typing SQL on a production ambient using `pgadmin3` tool, suddenly I mistyped and execute a UPDATE sentence on a biggerImportantTable without WHERE. Then desperately I use cancel query button on `pgadmin3`. After I look at a small sample of the rows in the table and it seems good. But I'm not sure of the database integrity. What is the state of my boss database?.

The log of `pgadmin3`:

```
-- Executing query:

UPDATE schema.big_important_table SET important_field = NULL;
********** Error **********

ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
SQL state: 57014
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel a DML statement (even with auto-commit enabled as pgAdmin does) the whole statement is rolled back.

So everything should be OK, nothing was changed.

Comment: Thanks. `pgadmin3` log flow is not clear also follows: execute query > executing query > cancel query > canceling > error canceling. ?

Comment: @jaundavid: sorry, no idea, I don't use pgAdmin